# WebRequest will not pass headers from ASP.NET MVC controller to Rest Wcf

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf

I have an ASP.NET MVC 4 project that when I make an HTTP call using a web request, the headers will not pass.

Here is My Code:

```
HttpWebRequest client = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        string svcCredentials = Convert.ToBase64String(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("user1" + ":" + "test"));
        client.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + svcCredentials);
        //Just some example code to parse the JSON response using the JavaScriptSerializer
        using (WebResponse svcResponse = (HttpWebResponse)client.GetResponse())
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(svcResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                string jsonTxt = sr.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
```

Comment: ... and the error message is?

Comment: i am getting Authorization value Null in WCF. so i am not able to validate userName and Password

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string encCred = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("user1" + ":" + "test"));
string credential = string.Format("{0} {1}", "Basic", encCred);
client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = credential;
```

Instead of:

```
client.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + svcCredentials);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your response. but Still i am getting Null value in WCF 
This is my code in WCF:
WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization];

Comment: Can you turn on the logging? So you can see the incoming message to check the header that is coming to the service.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730064(v=vs.110).aspx